# Why is finite elements method not part of electrical engineering curriculum?

Tags: finite-element-method

The question is straightforward. FEM is a third year course in mechanical engineering but not generally taught in electrical. Why is this?

Comment: Will electricians need it?

Comment: The only time I need to use FEM is when I'm doing something with magnetics, like motors and solenoids -- and I only know enough to be dangerous.  If I were to assigned to be part of a motor design, I'd hire a suitable expert (and those guys *do* know FEM).

Answer (score 1):

Mechanical engineers have to deal all the time with things like stress distributions in objects of finite size and noninfinite strength or velocity, temperature, and pressure distributions in large amounts of flowing gases and liquids. Nothing quite like this exists in the field of electrical engineering.

Comment: I think this displays a lack of understanding of numerical methods as applied to solids/fluids and the possible range of application. However, this sort of understanding is standard among most engineers and it's next to impossible to discuss the issue with them.

Comment: @BiswajitBanerjee, I speak from 34 years experience as a mechanical engineer in high tech. If you disagree with my answer you can write your own and post it here.

Answer (score 0):

The finite element method is used to solve problems where you need to find the electrical and magnetic fields.  The governing differential equations are the Maxwell's equations (either static or dynamic).

Any good engineering curriculum with have at least one course that deals with solving these equations (or their simplified forms) numerically.  The most popular numerical methods are finite differences, the method of moments, and finite elements.  However, undergraduate courses usually limit themselves to the first two and leave finite elements for graduate level courses.

Typical applications include computing the electromagnetic scattering (e.g., radar cross-sections) of objects, design of photonic crystals and metamaterals, reconstructing the electric field of the heart and brain from sparse samples, low level circuit and chip design, MEMS and radio-frequency engineering, wireless communication design, antenna design, remote sensing and subsurface scattering, etc.

The most popular multiphysics simulation software suites have paid large amounts to buy electromagnetic FEA software in recent years and they are used widely in industry.

Also, recent developments in exterior calculus for finite elements have made it easier to deal with issues that were causes by the large null space of the div and curl operators of the field in quasistatic problems.

I think FEA will become standard in undergraduate electrical engineering in a few years.

Comment: I disagree. The kind of curriculum you are talking about is aimed at creating more theoretical academics, not preparing engineers for the kinds of careers that most of them seek. A small handful of PhD students might possibly benefit from FEA...most practicing engineers can do without calculus.

Comment: To correctly use numerical software that uses FEM/FDM/etc you have to know how they work. I know that most engineers treat tools these as black boxes.  But that's not a feature that should be celebrated. It's true that most practicing engineers could do without any formal education.

Comment: I disagree - you don't need to know how the tools work, you need to know how to use them, which is a different question, and one which doesn't match the objectives of most academic courses (e.g. you can't easily ask exam questions about it!) A mech eng course on FE that teaches you how to write a toy version of 50-year-old computer methods (which is the content of some modern textbooks on the subject) is pretty worthless IMO. I say that having spend several decades developing FE software, and teaching engineers in industry how to use it.

Comment: Well, I see mechanical, structural, and civil engineers using FE wrongly all the time.  The reason is that they don't understand that they are solving PDEs and don't know the assumptions involved.  As a result they depend strongly on proof by authority, e.g., the software is "industry standard".  That may be because they are taught wrongly in UG.    I also see people using Kirchhoff's laws in the presence of inductive sources because they don't know the assumptions.  One can use epicycles to predict the motions of the planets.  If the use better models they can get it done quicker and better.